# Using gitlab-ci vars inside an ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, gitlab-ci, cicd, infrastructure-as-code

I want to set a remote environment inside a docker container using an Ansible playbook. This playbook will run from gitlab-ci with variables I set in in the Gitlab CI/CD confituration. How can I acheive that?

Here is the template I want to use. How do I set the `user_id` and `password` from the CI/CD variables?

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: Run XYZ Container
    docker_container:
      name: XYZ
      restart_policy: on-failure
      image: xxxxxxxxxxx
      container_default_behavior: "compatibility"
      env:
        USER_ID= $USER_ID
        PASSWORD= $PASSWORD
```

Comment: Use jinja2 template to set variable using CI/CD. Like {{ USER_ID }} instead of $USER_ID. USER_ID variable can be set when calling ansible-playbook.

Comment: Not sure what your goal is, if it's to add project variables using Ansible, consider looking at the module `gitlab_project_variable` (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/gitlab_project_variable_module.html#gitlab-project-variable-module).

Comment: use CI/CD variable and pass it in environment in CI jobs who launch ansible code.You can create file var and import it with ansible too.

Comment: @user1098490 OP wants to use the gitlab CI variables while launching an ansible script in a CI step, not to manage a project's CI variables from ansible.

Comment: If the goal is to use gitlab CI variables in Ansible-playbooks, I would've considered looking at passing extra variables to ansible, using `--extra-vars` , when calling the `ansible-playbook` in the CI/CD job. (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime). Which means you'll have to switch the `$USER_ID` with `{{ myVar }}` as pointed out by @Sriram, and run something like `ansible-playbook myPlaybook.yml -e myVar=${USER_ID}` in your CI/CD job.

Answer (score 7):

Since gitlab-ci variables are just environment variables inside your job, and since your ansible controller runs inside that job, you can use the [`env` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/env_lookup.html) to read them from the controller.

Please note that:

1. the [`docker_container` module's `env` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_container_module.html#parameter-env) expects a dict and not a new line separated string of bash like env vars definition like in your example.
2. as a security measure, you should either check that the vars are defined prior to using them (with an [`assert`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html)  or [`fail`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html) task) or use a default value in case they're not. My example uses a default value. For more on providing default value, you can see the [ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values) (and the [original jinja2 documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default) to understand that `d` is a an alias to `default`)

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: Run XYZ Container
    docker_container:
      name: XYZ
      restart_policy: on-failure
      image: xxxxxxxxxxx
      container_default_behavior: "compatibility"
      env:
        USER_ID: "{{ lookup('env', 'USER_ID') | d('defaultuser', true) }}"
        PASSWORD: "{{ lookup('env', 'PASSWORD') | d('defaultpass', true) }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

i wanted to use the CI_JOB_TOKEN so i used:

```
 tasks:
   - include_role: role_name
     vars:
       ci_job_token: "{{ lookup('env', 'CI_JOB_TOKEN') }}"
```